# Ideals and quotient rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I am trying to show that

(R/I)/(J/I) is isomorphic to R/J

I and J are both ideals of the ring R, and I is a subset of J.

How do I begin this proof?

Comment: I know the question I chose as a dupe is about groups, but the solution to the problem in either category is identical!

Comment: Most algebra texts contain a proof, and if you search for "isomorphism theorem" you will find proofs.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Define

$$\phi:R/I\to R/J\;\;,\;\;\phi(r+I):=r+J$$

Show this is a well defined function (i.e., $\;r+I=r'+I\implies r+J=r'+J\;$) and that it is an onto ring homomorphism. Now, what is its kernel? And then use the first isomorphism theorem.